# How can I take action on incoming Gmail emails (via a saved filter) that do not include a plus sign in the to line?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-search

I use email aliases for my email account to design incoming email filters for mail sent to me from different sources, for example:

- `me+newsletter@gmail.com`
- `me+bills@gmail.com`
- `me@gmail.com`

It's easy for me to set up incoming search filters for the "newsletter" or "bills" aliases, so I can select messages sent only to those labels. For example: `to:me+newsletter@gmail.com`.

However, I have not figured out a design for an incoming mail filter to take action on emails addressed to my "bare" email, `me@gmail.com`. I've tried what I thought would be an exact match, `to:"me@gmail.com"`, only to find that the filter selects email sent to all three addresses: `me@gmail.com`, `me+newsletter@gmail.com`, and `me+bills@gmail.com`.

What Gmail incoming mail filter will select *only* messages sent to `me@gmail.com` exactly so I can process them in some way (for example, forwarding them)?

Note: I filed [a very similar question recently](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/133440/how-can-i-filter-gmail-emails-that-do-not-include-a-plus-sign-in-the-to-line) but I realized after an answer was submitted that I hadn't made it clear that I want to take action upon incoming email to my bare address rather than simply post-process email already received.

Answer (score 1):

The filter you need to use in the `Includes the words` field is:

```
to:username@gmail.com -(username+newsletter@gmail.com OR username+bills@gmail.com)
```

Please try it out and let us know how it goes.

Comment: I know you had a [similar question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/133440/117311) posted as well.Have you tried this new answer? Did it work for you?

Comment: Please check the updated answer.